# Dynamic date in getlistitemchanges method

Tags: soap, wsdl, xquery

I am trying to use this GetListItemChanges method:

```
<GetListItemChanges xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<listName>States At A Glance</listName>
<viewFields></viewFields>    
<since>2013-08-29T 19:52:52Z</since>
<contains></contains>
</GetListItemChanges>
```

Is there a way to use dynamic date in the "since" tag.

for example I want the field values that are changes within 30 days from the current day.

---

Update:

I read that current datetime has to be in UTC format, so tried the following code:

```
(: SOAP payload, actual query goes here:)
let $soap-payload := ('<GetListItemChanges           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<listName>States At A Glance</listName>
<viewName>
<FieldRef Name="ows_Title" />
</viewName>
<since>fn:concat(fn:substring(fn:current-dateTime(),1,19), 'Z')</since>
</GetListItemChanges>')
```

But the code didn't work, go the following error message:

```
XQuery Engine error. syntax error, unexpected "'QName'", expecting "')'". Connection String: XQUERY;UID=ms\orbitad;. Connection String: XQUERY;UID=ms\orbitad;.
```

Any idea, why code isn't working??

I actually want to do current date - 30.

First I'll have this work and then I will current-date - 30.

@Jens Erat, 
The UTC datetime is in the following format - "2014-01-23T 00:00:00Z" . There is a space between the "T" and hours "00".

So, I modified your code a little bit and used the following code
    {fn:concat(fn:substring((fn:current-dateTime() - xs:dayTimeDuration('P30D'))    cast as xs:string, 1, 11), ' ', fn:substring((fn:current-dateTime() - xs:dayTimeDuration('P30D')) cast as xs:string, 12, 8), 'Z')}.

But, it throwed the error: axiom_node_create_from_buffer failed.

```
Unable to create payload for SOAP Request. Check payload in xquery. 
Error type: XQuery Engine error. Module description accessed has invalid state
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your updated code.

- I guess you don't the XML as string, but XML content? Then you'll have to remove the quotes.
- The error message is because you're terminating the large string you're assigning to `$soap-payload` around `'Z'`, then there is a `Z`, and then begins the next string. This is no valid XQuery code. You'd have to escape the quotes (like `\'Z\'`), but this still would not execute the code.
- The code isn't executed: Put curly brackets `{...}` around the code (if you actually want XML, not a large string) or end the string, calculate the new date, add the rest of the string and concatenate everything.

Use this code if you want a string returned:

```
let $soap-payload := concat('<GetListItemChanges           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<listName>States At A Glance</listName>
<viewName>
<FieldRef Name="ows_Title" />
</viewName>
<since>', fn:concat(fn:substring((fn:current-dateTime() - xs:dayTimeDuration('P30D')) cast as xs:string, 1, 19), 'Z'), '</since>
</GetListItemChanges>')
```

If you want XML:

```
let $soap-payload := <GetListItemChanges           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<listName>States At A Glance</listName>
<viewName>
<FieldRef Name="ows_Title" />
</viewName>
<since>{ fn:concat(fn:substring((fn:current-dateTime() - xs:dayTimeDuration('P30D')) cast as xs:string, 1, 19), 'Z') }</since>
</GetListItemChanges>
```

Comment: String to be returned, my code - let $soap-payload := ('<GetListItemChanges xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<listName>States At A Glance</listName>
<since>', fn:concat(fn:substring((fn:current-dateTime() - xs:dayTimeDuration('P30D')) cast as xs:string, 1, 11), ' ', fn:substring((fn:current-dateTime() - xs:dayTimeDuration('P30D')) cast as xs:string, 12, 8), 'Z') ,'</since>
</GetListItemChanges>') error - "Unable to create payload for SOAP Request. Check payload in xquery."